# Enviar dados de um formulário para página html

Tags: php, html, css, formulário

Pessoal tenho um formulário de contato que envia as informações para um email.

Porem eu gostaria que ao invés de mandar para o email, ele gerasse um página html e mandasse essas informações pra ela.

Isso é possível?

**PHP:**

```
<?php

/* Valores recebidos do formulÃ¡rio  */
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$replyto = $_POST['replyto']; // Email que serÃ¡ respondido
$mensagem_form = $_POST['mensagem'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];

/* DestinatÃ¡rio e remetente - EDITAR SOMENTE ESTE BLOCO DO CÃ“DIGO */
$to = "email@email.com";
$remetente = "email@email.com"; // Deve ser um email vÃ¡lido do domÃ­nio

/* CabeÃ§alho da mensagem  */
$boundary = "XYZ-" . date("dmYis") . "-ZYX";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers.= "From: $remetente\n";
$headers.= "Reply-To: $replyto\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";  
$headers.= "$boundary\n"; 

/* Layout da mensagem  */
$corpo_mensagem = " 
<strong>Nome:</strong> $nome 
<br><br><strong>Email:</strong> $replyto
<br><br><strong>Assunto:</strong> $assunto
<br><br><strong>Mensagem:</strong> $mensagem_form
";

/* FunÃ§Ã£o que codifica o anexo para poder ser enviado na mensagem  */
if(file_exists($arquivo["tmp_name"]) and !empty($arquivo)){

    $fp = fopen($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"],"rb"); // Abri o arquivo enviado.
    $anexo = fread($fp,filesize($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"])); // Le o arquivo aberto na linha anterior
    $anexo = base64_encode($anexo); // Codifica os dados com MIME para o e-mail 
    fclose($fp); // Fecha o arquivo aberto anteriormente
    $anexo = chunk_split($anexo); // Divide a variÃ¡vel do arquivo em pequenos pedaÃ§os para poder enviar
    $mensagem = "--$boundary\n"; // Nas linhas abaixo possuem os parÃ¢metros de formataÃ§Ã£o e codificaÃ§Ã£o, juntamente com a inclusÃ£o do arquivo anexado no corpo da mensagem
    $mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n"; 
    $mensagem.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n\n";
    $mensagem.= "$corpo_mensagem\n"; 
    $mensagem.= "--$boundary\n"; 
    $mensagem.= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."\n";  
    $mensagem.= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$arquivo["name"]."\"\n";  
    $mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";  
    $mensagem.= "$anexo\n";  
    $mensagem.= "--$boundary--\r\n"; 
}
    else // Caso nÃ£o tenha anexo
    {
        $mensagem = "--$boundary\n"; 
        $mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n"; 
        $mensagem.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n\n";
        $mensagem.= "$corpo_mensagem\n";
}

/* FunÃ§Ã£o que envia a mensagem  */
if(mail($to, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers))
{
    echo "<script>location.href='obrigado.php'</script>";
} 
    else
    {
        echo "<br><br><center><b><font color='red'>Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem!";
}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html{
width: 100%;
height: 125%;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:22px;
line-height: 1.3;
}
.bg_video{
position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -1000;
background: url(URL-FUNDO) no-repeat;
background-size: cover; }
.body{
padding:50px;
background: rgba(0.9);
margin: 0px auto 40px auto;
max-width: 100%;
border-radius: 50px;
}
.body h1{
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-size:40px;
}
.body p{
margin: 1.6em 0;
}

</style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body">



<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="envia.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">





<body style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent;" alink="#000099" link="#000099" vlink="#990099">
<video autoplay="" loop="" poster="URL-FUNDO" class="bg_video"> <source src="video/bg.webm" type="video/webm"> <source src="video/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </source> </source></video>
<div class="cabecalho">
<a id='inicio'></a>


<table
 style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 100px; text-align: center;"><p>


</p>

    <p>
        <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: bold;">Nome:</span></big><br />
        <input type="text" required="required" size="40" name="nome" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px">
    </p>

    <p>
        <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: bold;">Email:</span></big><br />
        <input type="text" required="required" size="40" name="replyto" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px">
    </p>

    <p>
        <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: bold;">Assunto:</span></big><br />
        <input type="text" required="required" size="40" name="assunto" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px">
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="file" name="arquivo">

    </p>
<p>

<p>
        <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: bold;">Mensagem:</span></big><br />
    <textarea required="required" name="mensagem" id="texto" cols="40" rows="7" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px"></textarea>
</p>


<p>

     <button type="image" name="Enviar" value="Enviar"><img style="width: 130px; height: auto;" src="../img/enviar.png"></button>

  </p>
</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mandar como? HTML pelo email? Acessar o HTML por um sistema interno?

Comment: Ao invés de mandar os dados do  formulário para o email, mandar para uma página html.

Comment: Você não pode simplesmente mandar pro HTML, precisa salvar em algum lugar pra acessar esses dados que podem ser exibidos em um HTML

Comment: Para onde eu posso mandar que não seja um email?

Comment: Geralmente um banco de dados, mas também pode salvar em arquivos

Comment: Certo, se puder gostaria que me disse-se como salvar em arquivos.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

No seu formulário troca o `action="envia.php"` para a página que você quer enviar os dados do formulário. Depois você recebe esses dados e insere diretamente na página para ser exibido.

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar o phpmailer e adicionar um arquivo html no body... aqui tem o projeto
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
no github tem um exemplo e nesta parte você insere o caminho do seu html

```
 /Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```